# Multi-Threading in J2ME and LWUIT

Tags: java, multithreading, java-me, lwuit

I want to make dialog box to be shown while I load some data from the web service
I'm using the LWUIT,

The following is the code

```
public class LoaderAnimation extends Container implements Runnable {

private Thread t;
private boolean running = false;

public LoaderAnimation() {
}

public void start() {
    running = true;
    t = new Thread(this);
    t.start();
}

public void run() {
    while (running) {

            // do something
            t.sleep(150);
    }
}

public void stop() {
    running = false;
}
}
```

what happens now that it runs but the code of calling the web service has stop working

that is the calling of it

```
public static void showLoaderScreen ()
    {
        dialog = new Dialog();
        dialog.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        canvas = new LoaderAnimation();
        dialog.addComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER , canvas);
        canvas.start();
        dialog.show();
    }

public static void dismissLoaderScreen ()
{
    canvas.stop();
    dialog.dispose();
}
```

Comment: does code snippet you posted compile? As far as I can tell, [t.sleep(150)](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep(long) "API javadocs") throws `InterruptedException` but there's no catch - and you certainly can't rethrow because it's `Runnable`. Also, you better declare running as `volatile`

Answer (score 1):

try this piece of code.

```
private void startLoader() {
    Dialog d = new Dialog();
    d.getStyle().setBgColor(0xffffff);
    d.getStyle().setBgTransparency(255);
    d.show(100, 250, 90, 150, true, false);
    d.setAutoDispose(true);
    try {
        Thread.sleep(30);
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    d.dispose();
    new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {

        public void run() {

            new Loader().start();
        }
    }, 30);
}
```

Loader class we can write parsing stuff or web service handling etc.

```
 class Loader extends Thread 

{        public void run() {

            try {

                ServiceTypesScreen st = new ServiceTypesScreen();
                st.init();
            } catch (Exception e) {                    
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
}
```